# How to return all aspnet_compiler errors (not just those in first directory)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnet-compiler

Is there a way to get the aspnet_compiler to go through all views and return *all* errors, rather than just the errors in the current view directory?

For example, lets say I have a project that has a bunch of folders...

- `Views`

  - `Folder1`
  - `Folder2`
  - `Folder3`
  - `Folder4`

Two of them (`Folder2` and `Folder3`) have errors. aspnet_compiler will run, and only return the errors it comes across in `Folder2`. It won't return those in `Folder3` at the same time. Once I fix the errors in `Folder2` and run it again, it'll then pick up the ones in the `Folder3`. I fix those. And then have to run the tool again, and again until it's all fixed.

This is getting annoying!!

For reference, here's the command I use:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler -v / -p "C:\path\to\project"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

11 years later, I grew tired of re-running `aspnet_compiler` myself and came up with *one weird trick*...

- Write a simple `.exe` (or Linqpad project) that loads `aspnet_compiler.exe` into your process.
- Set-up an event-handler to `AppDomain.FirstChanceException` to be notified of all `HttpCompileException` instances.

  - These are caught by `aspnet_compiler`'s `Main()` method, which fails at the first try.
  - Save the filename that caused the `HttpCompileException` in a `HashSet`.
- Then run `aspnet_compiler`'s `Main` method.
- If an `HttpCompileException` is thrown, then your program has the name of the file that failed, so then add that file to the `-x` compiler exclusion-list and re-run `aspnet_compiler`'s `Main` method again.
- And loop until it completes with no errors - and you'll have a list of *all* files with blocking errors.

(I'm still tidying-up my Linqpad program that does this, I'll post it to this answer shortly). I wonder if @DanAtkinson can still use it...

Comment: Thank you. I'm no longer using anything that required compiled views in this way so the question is no longer relevant to me. If you update your answer with the Linqpad code you mentioned - and mention me in a comment - then I'll take a look and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm ... rather than doing this via command prompt you can have your project build settings to do this for you automatically. Edit your project file in a text editor and add this settings in there if not already ...

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'"> 
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)..\$(ProjectName)" />
</Target>
```

This should compile all your views and return any compile time errors if any. Additionally for ASP.NET MVC projects, you might want to enable the `MvcBuildViews` property by setting it to `true` as it is disabled by default.

```
...
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I already do this, but because it blocks the UI, I tend to run it every now and again in the command window.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the problem of viewing **all** errors at once (or did I miss something?).  Useful answer, but not for getting all errors...